# Detect template parameter type

Tags: c++, c++11

Can I detect in a template function or template class the type of the template parameter?
I want to optimize my function for some types (int/float/vectors).
One solution would be to overload a function for any possible type. 
However, I was just curious whether I can make a type check with cxx11?

```
template <class T>
T foo<T>::apply(T sample)
{
  // if (T == int)
  // ..

  // if (T == float)
  // ..
}
```

Comment: You use a template specialization instead.

Comment: Theoretically, the compiler knows at compile time the type. Why I can't check the type?

Comment: Not only _theoretically_. The type is known and resolved at compile time.

Comment: If you're asking for something like `static if`, it has been proposed and you can read up on that proposal's reception.

Comment: If you want to dispatch according to some traits of the type, you may use tag dispatching.